# Simple challenge to learn curl

Tags: html, curl, token, element, postman

I am trying to learn curl commands to click a website button in the background/without opening it/from an external place (as Android apps like Tasker allows). After huge effort, all I have working so far is that I have used Postman to reproduce the cUrl request and so it works from there.

What I am trying to do now is use that Postman code within Tasker on Android which allows cURL. In Android Chrome, I have used view-source:http://imdb.com to get a session token as Tasker uses webview so I believe that is usually sufficient.

What I am struggling to work through is all the likely unnecessary code below spat out by Postman. I've tried a colossal number of combinations/attempts but with no luck.

With the token changed for security, below I have included Postman's original code that works from Postman, the session token I took from Android Chrome and the final code I mashed by simply replacing all incidents of `session-token=\"` from the first block, with my Android Chrome token.

Even better as I tend to learn best by comparing examples, if they had time to simply delete/amend the code so that what worked in Postman, would then work on Android webview.

Postman code:

```
curl -X PUT \

https://www.imdb.com/watchlist/tt1794908 \

-H 'accept: */*' \

-H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \

-H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \

-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \

-H 'cookie: session-id=144-1658623-3111269; session-id-time=2157045427; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; session-token=\"gKbykLoLLvCL7tOLDFz2Wqpss6PinsdGP5T3ZbGWR0BC3yABYjeTtXWBbk86VLIsGCA7o8PGpLCvgsnAJC7KKipiuooFkwSBCrjqTCJSBrIV+xXGMSfOOzcXR5nPUWptILjh90YMFSnUrM//m9FG+tR4UQNUBzJwUO5xkFRZgK8ZOljFvDBqpXRkIXvXzcwEeczxv5G2P5M=\"; x-main=\"nl@UH8kmtOiLhvf0CpQLGonksKmGPbMqoyC94qK3XZVLrk78LD9f@CKvB6zt2u7a\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBIMOfKgr8S6O1J0FRaz666mhSlNlUad2bw0K3b_iqwtXewVYQ8Hpgu9UEX-IWD62djBO5bfEs76QBh0WLyg7C7X8AknMPgrmMv2akolLWyjmUK72JP6hQVTXrk93LmHXuCH0cdqh5PXKcmia0MZi7ftoPhnLvZIRRmj66nRu-JiYhECmk7yTE--5vjhYoPO3zsrMx_Q6yfF8Q2AbvZ7wQp8iFLttRdOgDAf81Jp2NgByK-um-bFGgsM5M0l3RFa9NbUp7KgDalX6MYpK4QpVrpRR5PuuhpEWvPfhybBwlN4P55Eahlc-pt4shtehEGe9WYyiGRjjgyjdGRrx5_C2wPtZQHQCP02BKTo5pCU-mniiCSAOvShNneSWv5WrLmHA2l_jkEFA2X4DZFTUAVK7s4eGq; sess-at-main=\"bVSUVKCL4H3+HU5E3uzFa8lt04/XiQ/3AP4kii9rmIE=\"; id=BCYoDd7dw8LKxFiPcx5lBBy4T7XRwbVIRHvIvZ0t-oNxZ0Rj48ucoid5YOSd_VFBcZpGtflIcNcl%0D%0A_O8FvKs4Z9C6AAKXiaaepgxJYbaG9oYGskJNhP55eo6VhaAVidHB_An7HYmZt6jy1qbqBzkn18hn%0D%0A6qlamXIEgjKSIk8w0woH26R_ZUclt8KoqHsm3cbGFgFV7uVVyrYueUwly4dZEfUV_A%0D%0A; sid=BCYv70H47Pcj7K-6IeVOh2suTkqZNM--9CQLKNNvFMW4v9MEBbyox7PU9EAq4f3SsHsw3JxdupuK%0D%0AIguSc5QSqgzwH9qC1_kZhtGDD8aGOrvbyeGELLHluqPzllKkadPNRyLwuzi4ilSpJ5B_etTpjhJR%0D%0AtA%0D%0A; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; uu=BCYqz4gz3JlewYq-1NqR7THu-btEJC0oWfyxmOaRzYeWAwsymG1qDqYxujnqS-MZDWDOeAV8YCMk%0D%0ACa3sl9_1ippQfXvS578qbbOyZq2rpTFIr9jfUn6V8CoH1-vvMROz5IxlUv8wu6tEKYLnRQMJUnsw%0D%0A_hO9YKMMDQ92o0W88XwEcvmRWAdlk2wdOUDnBxp3U05N67BqLZrlb1wcsOgni7ylw01gSrVPzZRS%0D%0A0nZ6GrG2xsUkvzZmecf_69eRny0rODKwsMh_nrs3Q-AwE0lUJeOKRaNNclwwNoArcbIHz4Rv6E4%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B970%2C270%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-RF8BSHB8JC7WE84DZCMD|1529680409683&adb:adblk_no; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; session-id=146-9367377-5711811; session-id-time=2160478488; session-token=\"MMkMlv9RBMTY5FKsNgLqkJTTnqn1WRuexcY/rDFsaPFuuBtaccyxKXntDJBVNCFKTBLfRtfWCRqTpZ2//IlBUF1IgvkT8jn/eLAeb9pTnSj31Og79EWW5LOyV94ab+MkluUlQveyIZPmVnt2ZeeaxcPV4PRsxD5kYuTIfN2TV1q53GKJLqiYIMmnyrWR49jR7wIgf8OfldtgWElyJLIYoA==\"; x-main=\"iRKcY1VFDwj4QO1VI?kGgCUw?lxxrfkkJZ5EHzjOuCwHxOEOFk7h@IP@FDJdSS53\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBINMGkBEW3Uif2HtF7SWzKmYTVXg06Zt-2XNSuFm6hw_Bu9CW-z6QFuls0gD8ZIRka4O1ZDvLXqJKjaBdWZ7iBrHK6w5XI-ZBap3zxCtJ9DH_IplkWJL5iKtRq8ESnuGoP_le1HcqGCnJz8iW1C1tyQFPkXgZAdSyuhznDtHgB2Q7ZEL3xqXINRhKN_sMvfXsUJJ1U-me9KcHOE-y9tcohAuxFh09zTGiqJfT2zucaIVGQ1oDv_RPYUYt1maIzB5lqhnH0T4Yb9nRIFfr7jY6jAo7V9OofYpkE--FiYWmWakNCURNLZVtZ9v0pJEnAUr50c-jUz3HJqmzbCuf35RZn9GdCJh-P-c7_H4-qeOji9-lUOggHypvx0xY-OvdVmDm0et9ORWfJezd_Y7VWtXPSS4Y; sess-at-main=\"BHxon0DRXlcgFmRAIJpmyktSPXOsUM8nvmN7JrtDEM0=\"; id=BCYu_-xByZMKH7nwd2uATZm9MMe90-naJXlJqz_LcB6AOAWJ7oDUlEK5bMxeo8dyEbtd4gF620Cm%0D%0AN1yH6-MEggAhua4Pmmdv482vWPGy0g3O-aRAmPUfY7xZI0KBDUYLhWBUJUYeaDxNGzYB4pFyuqZ1%0D%0Ac2gTYvY3_YaV0rGz-d9Ib6KMSZBUhXgrZ6-9wrcOa82LA7OUfyX3vz9KOj-WoMpN8g%0D%0A; uu=BCYtNop9foT4_N6U_ubfz2-DQoN5_Li8uwu72IXyOuS-ofT0dF8w4p6Bn4NbC64o2fz3ZH1Pyyf4%0D%0AvBn-Dxll-HDwXSaye15GCEF4HLxGpLCdfyF7dbyRLY2PqLL5kaiubf8gYVMAagbcCfbTcbEMO61B%0D%0ATKlWt8cESQa2L6PE3RmTFAWlb6QueCUb-lnznodwsu5oWHYDWQ-zewFlXaZwDPKLE_k-4Fq7X1td%0D%0AFAEdnALx7_PRRkoyNr_VifTPilien7E2vmip_HX0VMCWJiS3EzzU5SdSLb2CD9AV7VDKw6OpElQ%0D%0A; sid=BCYiWNg1F96Si_940AuGyaEr1V43nam6jpwiy28p0W9Jr7n_x43-oKFzfVVNMUXBnCwm8XPG4-jT%0D%0Agqitzt_TvE9Cr_5cfi-lPPi48DUW479lCHGaslYZhfvGSgrBMjpnModW05bIM7A8PwNPQddVMB_s%0D%0AMQ%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-B1QGH6QTVEZN9V85W7YZ|1529758636729&adb:adblk_no' \

-H 'origin: https://www.imdb.com' \

-H 'postman-token: 3b188818-2bcb-8456-6108-6b78b42daded' \

-H 'referer: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1794908/?ref_=nv_sr_4' \

-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' \

-H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \

-b 'session-id=144-1658623-3111269; session-id-time=2157045427; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; session-token=\"gKbykLoLLvCL7tOLDFz2Wqpss6PinsdGP5T3ZbGWR0BC3yABYjeTtXWBbk86VLIsGCA7o8PGpLCvgsnAJC7KKipiuooFkwSBCrjqTCJSBrIV+xXGMSfOOzcXR5nPUWptILjh90YMFSnUrM//m9FG+tR4UQNUBzJwUO5xkFRZgK8ZOljFvDBqpXRkIXvXzcwEeczxv5G2P5M=\"; x-main=\"nl@UH8kmtOiLhvf0CpQLGonksKmGPbMqoyC94qK3XZVLrk78LD9f@CKvB6zt2u7a\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBIMOfKgr8S6O1J0FRaz666mhSlNlUad2bw0K3b_iqwtXewVYQ8Hpgu9UEX-IWD62djBO5bfEs76QBh0WLyg7C7X8AknMPgrmMv2akolLWyjmUK72JP6hQVTXrk93LmHXuCH0cdqh5PXKcmia0MZi7ftoPhnLvZIRRmj66nRu-JiYhECmk7yTE--5vjhYoPO3zsrMx_Q6yfF8Q2AbvZ7wQp8iFLttRdOgDAf81Jp2NgByK-um-bFGgsM5M0l3RFa9NbUp7KgDalX6MYpK4QpVrpRR5PuuhpEWvPfhybBwlN4P55Eahlc-pt4shtehEGe9WYyiGRjjgyjdGRrx5_C2wPtZQHQCP02BKTo5pCU-mniiCSAOvShNneSWv5WrLmHA2l_jkEFA2X4DZFTUAVK7s4eGq; sess-at-main=\"bVSUVKCL4H3+HU5E3uzFa8lt04/XiQ/3AP4kii9rmIE=\"; id=BCYoDd7dw8LKxFiPcx5lBBy4T7XRwbVIRHvIvZ0t-oNxZ0Rj48ucoid5YOSd_VFBcZpGtflIcNcl%0D%0A_O8FvKs4Z9C6AAKXiaaepgxJYbaG9oYGskJNhP55eo6VhaAVidHB_An7HYmZt6jy1qbqBzkn18hn%0D%0A6qlamXIEgjKSIk8w0woH26R_ZUclt8KoqHsm3cbGFgFV7uVVyrYueUwly4dZEfUV_A%0D%0A; sid=BCYv70H47Pcj7K-6IeVOh2suTkqZNM--9CQLKNNvFMW4v9MEBbyox7PU9EAq4f3SsHsw3JxdupuK%0D%0AIguSc5QSqgzwH9qC1_kZhtGDD8aGOrvbyeGELLHluqPzllKkadPNRyLwuzi4ilSpJ5B_etTpjhJR%0D%0AtA%0D%0A; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; uu=BCYqz4gz3JlewYq-1NqR7THu-btEJC0oWfyxmOaRzYeWAwsymG1qDqYxujnqS-MZDWDOeAV8YCMk%0D%0ACa3sl9_1ippQfXvS578qbbOyZq2rpTFIr9jfUn6V8CoH1-vvMROz5IxlUv8wu6tEKYLnRQMJUnsw%0D%0A_hO9YKMMDQ92o0W88XwEcvmRWAdlk2wdOUDnBxp3U05N67BqLZrlb1wcsOgni7ylw01gSrVPzZRS%0D%0A0nZ6GrG2xsUkvzZmecf_69eRny0rODKwsMh_nrs3Q-AwE0lUJeOKRaNNclwwNoArcbIHz4Rv6E4%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B970%2C270%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-RF8BSHB8JC7WE84DZCMD|1529680409683&adb:adblk_no; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; session-id=146-9367377-5711811; session-id-time=2160478488; session-token=\"MMkMlv9RBMTY5FKsNgLqkJTTnqn1WRuexcY/rDFsaPFuuBtaccyxKXntDJBVNCFKTBLfRtfWCRqTpZ2//IlBUF1IgvkT8jn/eLAeb9pTnSj31Og79EWW5LOyV94ab+MkluUlQveyIZPmVnt2ZeeaxcPV4PRsxD5kYuTIfN2TV1q53GKJLqiYIMmnyrWR49jR7wIgf8OfldtgWElyJLIYoA==\"; x-main=\"iRKcY1VFDwj4QO1VI?kGgCUw?lxxrfkkJZ5EHzjOuCwHxOEOFk7h@IP@FDJdSS53\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBINMGkBEW3Uif2HtF7SWzKmYTVXg06Zt-2XNSuFm6hw_Bu9CW-z6QFuls0gD8ZIRka4O1ZDvLXqJKjaBdWZ7iBrHK6w5XI-ZBap3zxCtJ9DH_IplkWJL5iKtRq8ESnuGoP_le1HcqGCnJz8iW1C1tyQFPkXgZAdSyuhznDtHgB2Q7ZEL3xqXINRhKN_sMvfXsUJJ1U-me9KcHOE-y9tcohAuxFh09zTGiqJfT2zucaIVGQ1oDv_RPYUYt1maIzB5lqhnH0T4Yb9nRIFfr7jY6jAo7V9OofYpkE--FiYWmWakNCURNLZVtZ9v0pJEnAUr50c-jUz3HJqmzbCuf35RZn9GdCJh-P-c7_H4-qeOji9-lUOggHypvx0xY-OvdVmDm0et9ORWfJezd_Y7VWtXPSS4Y; sess-at-main=\"BHxon0DRXlcgFmRAIJpmyktSPXOsUM8nvmN7JrtDEM0=\"; id=BCYu_-xByZMKH7nwd2uATZm9MMe90-naJXlJqz_LcB6AOAWJ7oDUlEK5bMxeo8dyEbtd4gF620Cm%0D%0AN1yH6-MEggAhua4Pmmdv482vWPGy0g3O-aRAmPUfY7xZI0KBDUYLhWBUJUYeaDxNGzYB4pFyuqZ1%0D%0Ac2gTYvY3_YaV0rGz-d9Ib6KMSZBUhXgrZ6-9wrcOa82LA7OUfyX3vz9KOj-WoMpN8g%0D%0A; uu=BCYtNop9foT4_N6U_ubfz2-DQoN5_Li8uwu72IXyOuS-ofT0dF8w4p6Bn4NbC64o2fz3ZH1Pyyf4%0D%0AvBn-Dxll-HDwXSaye15GCEF4HLxGpLCdfyF7dbyRLY2PqLL5kaiubf8gYVMAagbcCfbTcbEMO61B%0D%0ATKlWt8cESQa2L6PE3RmTFAWlb6QueCUb-lnznodwsu5oWHYDWQ-zewFlXaZwDPKLE_k-4Fq7X1td%0D%0AFAEdnALx7_PRRkoyNr_VifTPilien7E2vmip_HX0VMCWJiS3EzzU5SdSLb2CD9AV7VDKw6OpElQ%0D%0A; sid=BCYiWNg1F96Si_940AuGyaEr1V43nam6jpwiy28p0W9Jr7n_x43-oKFzfVVNMUXBnCwm8XPG4-jT%0D%0Agqitzt_TvE9Cr_5cfi-lPPi48DUW479lCHGaslYZhfvGSgrBMjpnModW05bIM7A8PwNPQddVMB_s%0D%0AMQ%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-B1QGH6QTVEZN9V85W7YZ|1529758636729&adb:adblk_no'
```

Android Chrome token:

```
ADZkkzbxbdvsSCa_4cbDYKbNxxbmaLTPf_P3-uUh5-P_Za5nnR1HmrkrHTvurhD5VERJleT7dFFv%0D%0AEPmziwwCzN8LMsZYYZ3TqJbAJIucbxbGJWt6LXJfOOa46bY1m0W_HBOdbBkzvWX5KRj3aQbE2zh0%0D%0AQglsVfpNUR8qI_baesNlw3e8aSgKQ7Ey2P6sjKXUlEjueXHIUN6CZmEbxmwGZuBVb_ONJcFSFfG2%0D%0ARRikNA0tWOBhdTNwZCBJl5Qz62o_9CFkwjcxKbw4IhDt5KwMxsg0YQ%0D%0A&ref_=m_tt_wb_aiv
```

Amended code:

```
curl -X PUT \

https://www.imdb.com/watchlist/tt1794908 \

-H 'accept: */*' \

-H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \

-H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \

-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \

-H 'cookie: session-id=144-1658623-3111269; session-id-time=2157045427; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; session-token=\"ADZkkzbxbdvsSCa_4cbDYKbNxxbmaLTPf_P3-uUh5-P_Za5nnR1HmrkrHTvurhD5VERJleT7dFFv%0D%0AEPmziwwCzN8LMsZYYZ3TqJbAJIucbxbGJWt6LXJfOOa46bY1m0W_HBOdbBkzvWX5KRj3aQbE2zh0%0D%0AQglsVfpNUR8qI_baesNlw3e8aSgKQ7Ey2P6sjKXUlEjueXHIUN6CZmEbxmwGZuBVb_ONJcFSFfG2%0D%0ARRikNA0tWOBhdTNwZCBJl5Qz62o_9CFkwjcxKbw4IhDt5KwMxsg0YQ%0D%0A&ref_=m_tt_wb_aiv"; x-main=\"nl@UH8kmtOiLhvf0CpQLGonksKmGPbMqoyC94qK3XZVLrk78LD9f@CKvB6zt2u7a\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBIMOfKgr8S6O1J0FRaz666mhSlNlUad2bw0K3b_iqwtXewVYQ8Hpgu9UEX-IWD62djBO5bfEs76QBh0WLyg7C7X8AknMPgrmMv2akolLWyjmUK72JP6hQVTXrk93LmHXuCH0cdqh5PXKcmia0MZi7ftoPhnLvZIRRmj66nRu-JiYhECmk7yTE--5vjhYoPO3zsrMx_Q6yfF8Q2AbvZ7wQp8iFLttRdOgDAf81Jp2NgByK-um-bFGgsM5M0l3RFa9NbUp7KgDalX6MYpK4QpVrpRR5PuuhpEWvPfhybBwlN4P55Eahlc-pt4shtehEGe9WYyiGRjjgyjdGRrx5_C2wPtZQHQCP02BKTo5pCU-mniiCSAOvShNneSWv5WrLmHA2l_jkEFA2X4DZFTUAVK7s4eGq; sess-at-main=\"bVSUVKCL4H3+HU5E3uzFa8lt04/XiQ/3AP4kii9rmIE=\"; id=BCYoDd7dw8LKxFiPcx5lBBy4T7XRwbVIRHvIvZ0t-oNxZ0Rj48ucoid5YOSd_VFBcZpGtflIcNcl%0D%0A_O8FvKs4Z9C6AAKXiaaepgxJYbaG9oYGskJNhP55eo6VhaAVidHB_An7HYmZt6jy1qbqBzkn18hn%0D%0A6qlamXIEgjKSIk8w0woH26R_ZUclt8KoqHsm3cbGFgFV7uVVyrYueUwly4dZEfUV_A%0D%0A; sid=BCYv70H47Pcj7K-6IeVOh2suTkqZNM--9CQLKNNvFMW4v9MEBbyox7PU9EAq4f3SsHsw3JxdupuK%0D%0AIguSc5QSqgzwH9qC1_kZhtGDD8aGOrvbyeGELLHluqPzllKkadPNRyLwuzi4ilSpJ5B_etTpjhJR%0D%0AtA%0D%0A; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; uu=BCYqz4gz3JlewYq-1NqR7THu-btEJC0oWfyxmOaRzYeWAwsymG1qDqYxujnqS-MZDWDOeAV8YCMk%0D%0ACa3sl9_1ippQfXvS578qbbOyZq2rpTFIr9jfUn6V8CoH1-vvMROz5IxlUv8wu6tEKYLnRQMJUnsw%0D%0A_hO9YKMMDQ92o0W88XwEcvmRWAdlk2wdOUDnBxp3U05N67BqLZrlb1wcsOgni7ylw01gSrVPzZRS%0D%0A0nZ6GrG2xsUkvzZmecf_69eRny0rODKwsMh_nrs3Q-AwE0lUJeOKRaNNclwwNoArcbIHz4Rv6E4%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B970%2C270%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-RF8BSHB8JC7WE84DZCMD|1529680409683&adb:adblk_no; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; session-id=146-9367377-5711811; session-id-time=2160478488; session-token=\"ADZkkzbxbdvsSCa_4cbDYKbNxxbmaLTPf_P3-uUh5-P_Za5nnR1HmrkrHTvurhD5VERJleT7dFFv%0D%0AEPmziwwCzN8LMsZYYZ3TqJbAJIucbxbGJWt6LXJfOOa46bY1m0W_HBOdbBkzvWX5KRj3aQbE2zh0%0D%0AQglsVfpNUR8qI_baesNlw3e8aSgKQ7Ey2P6sjKXUlEjueXHIUN6CZmEbxmwGZuBVb_ONJcFSFfG2%0D%0ARRikNA0tWOBhdTNwZCBJl5Qz62o_9CFkwjcxKbw4IhDt5KwMxsg0YQ%0D%0A&ref_=m_tt_wb_aiv"; x-main=\"iRKcY1VFDwj4QO1VI?kGgCUw?lxxrfkkJZ5EHzjOuCwHxOEOFk7h@IP@FDJdSS53\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBINMGkBEW3Uif2HtF7SWzKmYTVXg06Zt-2XNSuFm6hw_Bu9CW-z6QFuls0gD8ZIRka4O1ZDvLXqJKjaBdWZ7iBrHK6w5XI-ZBap3zxCtJ9DH_IplkWJL5iKtRq8ESnuGoP_le1HcqGCnJz8iW1C1tyQFPkXgZAdSyuhznDtHgB2Q7ZEL3xqXINRhKN_sMvfXsUJJ1U-me9KcHOE-y9tcohAuxFh09zTGiqJfT2zucaIVGQ1oDv_RPYUYt1maIzB5lqhnH0T4Yb9nRIFfr7jY6jAo7V9OofYpkE--FiYWmWakNCURNLZVtZ9v0pJEnAUr50c-jUz3HJqmzbCuf35RZn9GdCJh-P-c7_H4-qeOji9-lUOggHypvx0xY-OvdVmDm0et9ORWfJezd_Y7VWtXPSS4Y; sess-at-main=\"BHxon0DRXlcgFmRAIJpmyktSPXOsUM8nvmN7JrtDEM0=\"; id=BCYu_-xByZMKH7nwd2uATZm9MMe90-naJXlJqz_LcB6AOAWJ7oDUlEK5bMxeo8dyEbtd4gF620Cm%0D%0AN1yH6-MEggAhua4Pmmdv482vWPGy0g3O-aRAmPUfY7xZI0KBDUYLhWBUJUYeaDxNGzYB4pFyuqZ1%0D%0Ac2gTYvY3_YaV0rGz-d9Ib6KMSZBUhXgrZ6-9wrcOa82LA7OUfyX3vz9KOj-WoMpN8g%0D%0A; uu=BCYtNop9foT4_N6U_ubfz2-DQoN5_Li8uwu72IXyOuS-ofT0dF8w4p6Bn4NbC64o2fz3ZH1Pyyf4%0D%0AvBn-Dxll-HDwXSaye15GCEF4HLxGpLCdfyF7dbyRLY2PqLL5kaiubf8gYVMAagbcCfbTcbEMO61B%0D%0ATKlWt8cESQa2L6PE3RmTFAWlb6QueCUb-lnznodwsu5oWHYDWQ-zewFlXaZwDPKLE_k-4Fq7X1td%0D%0AFAEdnALx7_PRRkoyNr_VifTPilien7E2vmip_HX0VMCWJiS3EzzU5SdSLb2CD9AV7VDKw6OpElQ%0D%0A; sid=BCYiWNg1F96Si_940AuGyaEr1V43nam6jpwiy28p0W9Jr7n_x43-oKFzfVVNMUXBnCwm8XPG4-jT%0D%0Agqitzt_TvE9Cr_5cfi-lPPi48DUW479lCHGaslYZhfvGSgrBMjpnModW05bIM7A8PwNPQddVMB_s%0D%0AMQ%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-B1QGH6QTVEZN9V85W7YZ|1529758636729&adb:adblk_no' \

-H 'origin: https://www.imdb.com' \

-H 'postman-token: 3b188818-2bcb-8456-6108-6b78b42daded' \

-H 'referer: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1794908/?ref_=nv_sr_4' \

-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' \

-H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \

-b 'session-id=144-1658623-3111269; session-id-time=2157045427; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; session-token=\"ADZkkzbxbdvsSCa_4cbDYKbNxxbmaLTPf_P3-uUh5-P_Za5nnR1HmrkrHTvurhD5VERJleT7dFFv%0D%0AEPmziwwCzN8LMsZYYZ3TqJbAJIucbxbGJWt6LXJfOOa46bY1m0W_HBOdbBkzvWX5KRj3aQbE2zh0%0D%0AQglsVfpNUR8qI_baesNlw3e8aSgKQ7Ey2P6sjKXUlEjueXHIUN6CZmEbxmwGZuBVb_ONJcFSFfG2%0D%0ARRikNA0tWOBhdTNwZCBJl5Qz62o_9CFkwjcxKbw4IhDt5KwMxsg0YQ%0D%0A&ref_=m_tt_wb_aiv"; x-main=\"nl@UH8kmtOiLhvf0CpQLGonksKmGPbMqoyC94qK3XZVLrk78LD9f@CKvB6zt2u7a\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBIMOfKgr8S6O1J0FRaz666mhSlNlUad2bw0K3b_iqwtXewVYQ8Hpgu9UEX-IWD62djBO5bfEs76QBh0WLyg7C7X8AknMPgrmMv2akolLWyjmUK72JP6hQVTXrk93LmHXuCH0cdqh5PXKcmia0MZi7ftoPhnLvZIRRmj66nRu-JiYhECmk7yTE--5vjhYoPO3zsrMx_Q6yfF8Q2AbvZ7wQp8iFLttRdOgDAf81Jp2NgByK-um-bFGgsM5M0l3RFa9NbUp7KgDalX6MYpK4QpVrpRR5PuuhpEWvPfhybBwlN4P55Eahlc-pt4shtehEGe9WYyiGRjjgyjdGRrx5_C2wPtZQHQCP02BKTo5pCU-mniiCSAOvShNneSWv5WrLmHA2l_jkEFA2X4DZFTUAVK7s4eGq; sess-at-main=\"bVSUVKCL4H3+HU5E3uzFa8lt04/XiQ/3AP4kii9rmIE=\"; id=BCYoDd7dw8LKxFiPcx5lBBy4T7XRwbVIRHvIvZ0t-oNxZ0Rj48ucoid5YOSd_VFBcZpGtflIcNcl%0D%0A_O8FvKs4Z9C6AAKXiaaepgxJYbaG9oYGskJNhP55eo6VhaAVidHB_An7HYmZt6jy1qbqBzkn18hn%0D%0A6qlamXIEgjKSIk8w0woH26R_ZUclt8KoqHsm3cbGFgFV7uVVyrYueUwly4dZEfUV_A%0D%0A; sid=BCYv70H47Pcj7K-6IeVOh2suTkqZNM--9CQLKNNvFMW4v9MEBbyox7PU9EAq4f3SsHsw3JxdupuK%0D%0AIguSc5QSqgzwH9qC1_kZhtGDD8aGOrvbyeGELLHluqPzllKkadPNRyLwuzi4ilSpJ5B_etTpjhJR%0D%0AtA%0D%0A; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; uu=BCYqz4gz3JlewYq-1NqR7THu-btEJC0oWfyxmOaRzYeWAwsymG1qDqYxujnqS-MZDWDOeAV8YCMk%0D%0ACa3sl9_1ippQfXvS578qbbOyZq2rpTFIr9jfUn6V8CoH1-vvMROz5IxlUv8wu6tEKYLnRQMJUnsw%0D%0A_hO9YKMMDQ92o0W88XwEcvmRWAdlk2wdOUDnBxp3U05N67BqLZrlb1wcsOgni7ylw01gSrVPzZRS%0D%0A0nZ6GrG2xsUkvzZmecf_69eRny0rODKwsMh_nrs3Q-AwE0lUJeOKRaNNclwwNoArcbIHz4Rv6E4%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B970%2C270%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-RF8BSHB8JC7WE84DZCMD|1529680409683&adb:adblk_no; ubid-main=131-1191112-1316016; GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY=W3sidSI6IjVZSWciLCJ0c2wiOjE1MjcxODY0MzAsIm52IjoxLCJ1cHQiOjE1MjcxODY0MjAsImx0IjoxNTI3MTg2NDMwfV0.; cache=BCYgSjjVaGBu8-SGq_UmXMMacVKoa7jx2iBbdImOoCBaIeWgRUI09BOLgzXWUypXLPNrFhpfcPVf%0D%0Ad2rJFsQgQ1nHwc-sxRuDgeMFM3eSxfzlAK8%0D%0A; session-id=146-9367377-5711811; session-id-time=2160478488; session-token=\"ADZkkzbxbdvsSCa_4cbDYKbNxxbmaLTPf_P3-uUh5-P_Za5nnR1HmrkrHTvurhD5VERJleT7dFFv%0D%0AEPmziwwCzN8LMsZYYZ3TqJbAJIucbxbGJWt6LXJfOOa46bY1m0W_HBOdbBkzvWX5KRj3aQbE2zh0%0D%0AQglsVfpNUR8qI_baesNlw3e8aSgKQ7Ey2P6sjKXUlEjueXHIUN6CZmEbxmwGZuBVb_ONJcFSFfG2%0D%0ARRikNA0tWOBhdTNwZCBJl5Qz62o_9CFkwjcxKbw4IhDt5KwMxsg0YQ%0D%0A&ref_=m_tt_wb_aiv"iRKcY1VFDwj4QO1VI?kGgCUw?lxxrfkkJZ5EHzjOuCwHxOEOFk7h@IP@FDJdSS53\"; at-main=Atza|IwEBINMGkBEW3Uif2HtF7SWzKmYTVXg06Zt-2XNSuFm6hw_Bu9CW-z6QFuls0gD8ZIRka4O1ZDvLXqJKjaBdWZ7iBrHK6w5XI-ZBap3zxCtJ9DH_IplkWJL5iKtRq8ESnuGoP_le1HcqGCnJz8iW1C1tyQFPkXgZAdSyuhznDtHgB2Q7ZEL3xqXINRhKN_sMvfXsUJJ1U-me9KcHOE-y9tcohAuxFh09zTGiqJfT2zucaIVGQ1oDv_RPYUYt1maIzB5lqhnH0T4Yb9nRIFfr7jY6jAo7V9OofYpkE--FiYWmWakNCURNLZVtZ9v0pJEnAUr50c-jUz3HJqmzbCuf35RZn9GdCJh-P-c7_H4-qeOji9-lUOggHypvx0xY-OvdVmDm0et9ORWfJezd_Y7VWtXPSS4Y; sess-at-main=\"BHxon0DRXlcgFmRAIJpmyktSPXOsUM8nvmN7JrtDEM0=\"; id=BCYu_-xByZMKH7nwd2uATZm9MMe90-naJXlJqz_LcB6AOAWJ7oDUlEK5bMxeo8dyEbtd4gF620Cm%0D%0AN1yH6-MEggAhua4Pmmdv482vWPGy0g3O-aRAmPUfY7xZI0KBDUYLhWBUJUYeaDxNGzYB4pFyuqZ1%0D%0Ac2gTYvY3_YaV0rGz-d9Ib6KMSZBUhXgrZ6-9wrcOa82LA7OUfyX3vz9KOj-WoMpN8g%0D%0A; uu=BCYtNop9foT4_N6U_ubfz2-DQoN5_Li8uwu72IXyOuS-ofT0dF8w4p6Bn4NbC64o2fz3ZH1Pyyf4%0D%0AvBn-Dxll-HDwXSaye15GCEF4HLxGpLCdfyF7dbyRLY2PqLL5kaiubf8gYVMAagbcCfbTcbEMO61B%0D%0ATKlWt8cESQa2L6PE3RmTFAWlb6QueCUb-lnznodwsu5oWHYDWQ-zewFlXaZwDPKLE_k-4Fq7X1td%0D%0AFAEdnALx7_PRRkoyNr_VifTPilien7E2vmip_HX0VMCWJiS3EzzU5SdSLb2CD9AV7VDKw6OpElQ%0D%0A; sid=BCYiWNg1F96Si_940AuGyaEr1V43nam6jpwiy28p0W9Jr7n_x43-oKFzfVVNMUXBnCwm8XPG4-jT%0D%0Agqitzt_TvE9Cr_5cfi-lPPi48DUW479lCHGaslYZhfvGSgrBMjpnModW05bIM7A8PwNPQddVMB_s%0D%0AMQ%0D%0A; as=%7B%22h%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%2C%22n%22%3A%7B%22t%22%3A%5B1008%2C135%5D%2C%22tr%22%3A%5B300%2C250%5D%2C%22in%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%22ib%22%3A%5B0%2C0%5D%7D%7D; csm-hit=tb:9HB24CGZJXAKWFMZESCV+s-B1QGH6QTVEZN9V85W7YZ|1529758636729&adb:adblk_no'
```

EDIT: typos/amended

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey, thanks! Sorry for not being very clear. I am trying to use a curl command or anything else; to click a website button in the background/without opening it/from an external place. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Just repeating what you said already in your original question does not count as an actual clarification.

Comment: Yes- you are completely right so please accept my apologies as I am very new to forums and couldn't think of a way to clarify it. What I'm basically trying to do is as I have in postman, to send a command to click on the 'add to watchlist' button on an IMDb page whilst being logged in. I think it works in postman because the token/cookie matches up from there but when I try to do it in Tasker, I am assuming it requires a cookie/token from the webview browser on Android which I believe tasker uses in the background when sending a commands. Hopefully that helps and huge thanks once again!

Comment: (When asking questions here, please keep your material brief and excise chatty material as much as you can. Replaces turns of phrase ("a chap cuts his teeth" to mean learning) with more literal variants to reduce confusion. This is an international Q&A, so readability is important).

Comment: Do you realize you can’t click buttons with postman or curl?